# rails user notifications for several models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

I'm still learning rails but want to be sure I'm heading in the right direction. For several of my models I want to let a list of users know that updates have been made when a new record is created for example. I'd like to tie this to an email and in-app notification(doesn't need to be AJAX), next page refresh is fine.

I've been reading up on observers some and I think that's what I want but they seem somewhat controversial based on the blogs I've read. Services like Pusher seem to be overkill for my needs.

Would this be a good solution for this scenario? Also, can anyone point me to some example code that I could emulate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/) if you are trying to learn. Best free code base I have seen. Also check out this book another great learning tool. [Agile Web Development with Rails (2nd edition)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails).There might be some newer ones out but I have not checked.

Comment: [Agile Web Development with Rails (3rd edition)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails) Just found the newest one

Comment: Haha just found the 4th edition [Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)